# I want the Button to fade in when the mouse is over a certain area (my first invisible UI element). And I want the Button then to be clickable

Tags: wpf, xaml

In my App, I have two overlapping UI Elements. When the mouse enters the first Element, the second will fade in and overlapp the first.
But because of the new displayed Element, the MouseLeave Element of the first will be called and the second will fade out again. (I'm listening to MouseEnter / MouseLeave of the first Elemenet).

When I set the property IsHitTestVisible="False" for the second Element, I Will get rid of the permanent fade in / fade out effect. But not I cannot click on the second Element anymore (It's a Button).

So my question is: Is there a way to make a Control (Button in my Case) Invisible to hits for the MouseEnter / MouseLeave events, but still be Visible for MouseClick and also change the Cursor to Hand when MouseOver?

Thank you for your help

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve?  https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @RobertHarvey I want the Button to fade in when the mouse is over a certain area (my first invisible UI element). And I want the Button then to be clickable.

Comment: Yes, but why? ...

Comment: @RobertHarvey I dont understand your question? Because the product owner wants me to?

Comment: It just seems like a lot of work (and very non-standard) without a rationale.

Comment: And understanding the reasoning would help us craft a better solution.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ill think about it, thanks so far

Comment: @user3292642: No, it doesn't handle raise `Click` events when `IsHitTestVisible` is `false`. Why don't you simply return from your handler(s) based on some logic before you fade in or out?